# Use AWS CLI to list certain managed policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to list `AWS (managed) policies` related to `CodeCommit` using `AWS CLI`.

I found `aws list-policies` but it doesn't seem to have a way to filter. It just returns ALL the policies.

I would like to return the same as if I was using the `console`

- AWSCodeCommitFullAccess
- AWSCodeCommitPowerUser
- AWSCodeCommitReadOnly

Anyone knows the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aws iam list-policies --query 'Policies[?starts_with(PolicyName,`AWSCodeCommit`)]'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jellycsc It works beautiful. I searched a lot without luck.

Answer (score 0):

when run commands to list anything in aws and then grep it with target information. as shown in below command.

```
aws iam list-policies --profile binsysmh  |grep -i commit
```

here you will also get arn for target policies which will help for next aws cli tasks. [image: here in action !!]

Note: this trick is only validate in Linux based terminal.